# Duplicate Cassandra node from one node to two nodes without repair?

Tags: cassandra

Is there an easy way to move from having a single node to two nodes that both have a full copy of the data. In the past when I added a node, I had to wait for the second node to take half of the data and then I had to muck around to make them full replicas again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy over the sstables directly and that way when the node starts up, it can access its data directly without needing streaming.  This is how it should work:  go to your data folder on your old node and copy over directories matching for the keyspaces you want to migrate, as well as schema directories inside `system`.  Copy these over to your new node's data directory (create it if necessary).  Then configure the new node and have it join the cluster as usual.  I believe you'll have access to your new data at this point without further migrations.

See a [blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading) on this topic for more details, especially on using a more refined approach with the help of `sstableloader` tool.